# Finding out the possible combination of a given number

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

Used the code below to find out the possible combination of a given number.
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

However, if a negative value is in the population, this formula would not work. Is there any amendments that can be made in order to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

---

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([-17896,-4774,-1472,701,912,2848,3431,3966], -12284)
```

Answer (score 0):

at first look: the second check `if s >= target: return` works only in positive inputs case. When you have negative values in input, the partial sum can be greater than the destination. just disable this check.

```
sum([-17896, -4774, -1472, 701, 912, 2848, 3431, 3966])=-12284
```